# Sharing individual web pages on Facebook & LinkedIn causes lookup to come from home page instead of being page-specific

Tags: html, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a very specific set of defined tags that appear uniquely in the `<head></head>` of each page:

```
    <!-- Title -->
    <title>{{ $title }}</title>

    <!-- Meta description definitions have the potential to have Markdown formatted content -->
    {{ $meta_description := .Params.meta_description | markdownify | plainify }}

    <!-- Meta Description -->
    <meta name="description" content={{ $meta_description }} />

    <!-- Facebook Open Graph Meta Tags -->
    <meta name="title" property="og:title" content={{ $title }} />
    <meta name="description" property="og:description" content={{ $meta_description }} />
    <meta name="image" property="og:image" content={{ .Params.logo }} />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="627" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="{{ $url }}" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="{{ $site_name }}" />

    <!-- Twitter Meta Tags -->
    <meta name="twitter:title" content={{ $title }} />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content={{ $meta_description }} />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="{{ $site }}" />
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="{{ $creator }} " />
```

When viewing the page source per-page, the correct values are displayed on each individual page.

However, when using LinkedIn's [Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/) as well as Facebook's [Inspector](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) they consistently only pull meta information from the homepage when showing the preview. This is consistent with the behavior shown when actually attempting to share a webpage. In fact, using Facebook's debugging tool, it specifically states:

- Input URL    ->  https://www.mywebsite.com/mywebpage/correctly/input/
- og:url Meta Tag  ->  https://www.mywebsite.com/

Which clearly shows that even though the input URL is defined, it's pulling the meta tag specifically and only from the home page.

Why is this? How do I correct this behavior so it pulls it correctly per-page or per-article being shared?

How can I determine why LinkedIn, Facebook, & other social media websites are pulling the meta information directly from the homepage, rather than the page-specific URL being shared?

Comment: https://www.mywebsite.com/mywebpage/correctly/input/ is the real URL? Without the real URL it is impossible to tell what you are doing wrong

Comment: @WizKid It is not the real URL. It's a placeholder meant to illustrate the structure of the returned URLs. Why would it matter? The question pertains to: How can I determine why LinkedIn, Facebook, & other social media websites are pulling the meta information directly from the homepage, rather than the page-specific URL being shared?

Comment: If the debug tool says, `og:url Meta Tag -> https://www.mywebsite.com/`, then that most likely means you set that tag wrong.

Comment: Yes it matter because we can't help debugging the problem.

Comment: @CBroe the debug tool points to my homepage URL rather than the page-specific URL. You can see exactly how the meta information was set above. It exactly matches the format requested by all major media sharing websites (that I can tell), and all of my images exactly fit within the parameters requested. My question is again: why, and how, can these sites by pulling from the home page meta information rather than the page-specific URL being provided? What causes that redirect? At what point in the pipeline? Would it be server side? The result would be different if it was incorrect tags.

Comment: The debug tool usually shows what meta information & possibly redirects it followed, to arrive at the new URL.